# Fails to create a Cloud66 stack

Tags: vps, ruby-on-rails, cloud, cloud-hosting

I'm using Cloud66 and trying to set up a stack from my git repository. Cloud66 however returns the error:

```
Analysis error: The space character ‘ ’ is not allowed in your database username or password in your config/database.yml file - please remove this character and try again.
```

What could be the cause of this error?
In `database.yml` in my Rails application looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: 0.0.0.0
  pool: 5
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets.POSTGRES_USERNAME %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets.POSTGRES_PASSWORD %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

The username and password in `secrets.yml` only contain letters and numbers. What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

check this out:
http://community.cloud66.com/articles/sharing-a-database-between-stacks

you should change following lines to below:

```
    username: "<%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_USERNAME']%>"
    password: "<%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD']%>"
```